# Is it possible to route an email2case from one mailbox with threadid to other as a different case with the same mail chain?

Tags: apex, case, email2case

Need some help for the below scenario :

Scenario 1 : We have 6 different email2case mailboxes, where the customer sent an email to wrong mailbox and a case was created and the representative who started working on it identified it was a wrong email, so informed the customer to shoot the email to the correct email. Here in this case the customer simply removed the TO address and added the new email2case email, but still the emails are reflecting in the same case because of the threadid.

What is the possible solution to fix it in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Thread Id is Removed then only new cases will created and this will not be attached to case.No its not possible to create new case with Thread Id.If you have Thread Id only email will be attached to existing case.No New case will be created.

For More Info:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176597&type=1
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231299&type=1